# Ubuntu 12.04 can't discover my wireless

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I'm using a dual boot Eee PC 1015PX with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. I had been using 13.04, then 13.10 on this netbook and the wireless worked perfectly. I have since replaced 13.xx with a fresh install of 12.04 (because I couldn't get other things working on 13.xx) and it now cannot see my WiFi. I used a LiveUSB, and it picked up my WiFi, but once I installed the full operating system, it no longer picks it any wireless networks.

According to [notebookscheck.net](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Asus-Eee-PC-1015PX-Netbook.70557.0.html), the 1015PX has the Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [official documentation for network connections](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-wireless.html)?

There is a [section dedicated to your problem](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-find.html). You can edit your wireless connection to add the SSID and password:

- click on the Dash Home
- type Network/hit Enter
- ensure Airplane Mode is OFF
- select Wireless and ensure it is ON
- select Options
- enter the Network Name in SSID
- click the Wireless Security tab
- select your router security type from the drop-down menu (probably WPA &WPA2 Personal)
- enter the Password
- click Save...

If you have issues with the Network Manager after that, this post may be of some assistance: [Ubuntu 12.10 - network manager not listing wireless networks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213806/ubuntu-12-10-network-manager-not-listing-wireless-networks/345342#345342).

From your comment it sounds like there may be a driver or system issue.  Try an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Add the information from this command to your question by editing it:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

This will open up that file in a text editor.  Change the line that has managed= to:

```
managed=true
```

Next save and close the file. Reboot for good measure.

Comment: After going to Dash - Network, there's no Airplane Mode or Wireless options. Also, if I go to the wireless icon on the taskbar near the clock & click on edit connections, there is a wireless tab there, which has my wifi connection there. But it's not picking up my wifi, or my neighbours (which it does in Windows & did in 13.xx).

Comment: It doesn't sound like you looked through the documentation I posted; I would recommend reading it and trying the troubleshooter. I updated my answer in response to this new information.