# Broadcom 43142 is not working | HELP!

Tags: wireless, broadcom, iwlwifi

I have been install Ubuntu 14.04 on laptop Lenovo V580c.  All components are working OK, but WiFi isn't working.

I searched answers in Google, Askubuntu, but nothing works

Please, help

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What your output for `rfkill list`?

Comment: '0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no'

only this

Comment: It's not good that your wireless driver isn't listed there. Update your question with the output for `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new user on this website, I can't found button "edit question"

so I can show the list here
<code>
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:f3500000-f3507fff</code>

Comment: Okay, open up dash (super key) and type in Software & Updates then click on it. Navigate to the "Additional Drivers" tab. Is `Broadcom Corporation BCM43142` listed and selected?

Comment: Yes, it says 'This devise is using an alternative driver'.
I already did this operation a few hours ago, but nothing changed

Comment: What is your network indicator telling you? Is Wireless Networks displayed, but greyed out? Or is it just not there at all? Look here if you don't know where to look: http://www.techotopia.com/images/c/c9/Ubuntu_11_unity_network_menu.jpg

Comment: Wireless Networks is not displayed
https://pp.vk.me/c625528/v625528560/1be5e/lbIKHCcOeCY.jpg

Comment: What kernel are you using `uname -a`

Comment: After `uname -a`

`Linux vladyslac-Desktop 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing "fimware-b43-installer" offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730799/installing-fimware-b43-installer-offline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a computer with working internet go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download and select a mirror site to dowload from.  Copy the file to a USB, DVD or whatever to get in on the Ubuntu pc and double click on it to install

Comment: Just use thist method and listen to @Jeremy31; and @jessenorton; :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My laptop has the same wireless hardware. The easy solution is:
When you install ubuntu, check the box which says install third party software(wireless driver included in that).
Then everything works out of box.

Comment: to install them after an installation run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: No wifi, no connection to internet. The package ubuntu-restricted-extras is for things like playing video files, the wireless driver is not included.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I was assuming he still had ethernet but I just re-read his comments and noticed that he doesn't have ethernet on his machine.

Comment: I should reinstall my Ubuntu system? Can you give me a screenshot of that checkbox, please?

Comment: http://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ubuntu-install-third-party-software.png I also suggest selecting `Download updates while installing`

Comment: Yes, just reinstall, and you will see the check box. It's easy to see. Sorry I don't have a screenshot.

Comment: I see you have internet connection, here is another solution: click System settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > let it search and tick the result you want and then click apply change

Answer (score 0):

Do the command:

`sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

This will open up that file in a text editor. Change the line that has managed= to:

`managed=true`

Save and close the file, then do:

`sudo killall NetworkManager`

Logout and log back in again. Answer taken from: [Ubuntu 12.10 - network manager not listing wireless networks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213806/ubuntu-12-10-network-manager-not-listing-wireless-networks)

Comment: After that, I have some system problems, but wi-fi isn't shown

Comment: What system problems did it cause?

Comment: I have no idea, it shows, call me about problem, and hides

Comment: Okay, undo the changes. use `sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to open the network manager configuration file and remove the line `managed=true`. Save and exit, then run `sudo killall NetworkManager`. After logging out and in again follow the instructions by @Jeremy31 at: http://askubuntu.com/a/589786/143396

Comment: I'll try it now

Comment: YES)) I have wi-fi connection :)
thank all of you a lot)

but, how do you think, should I reinstall my system? because, sometimes ubuntu shows me some problems...

Comment: If you do a clean install you'll probably need to repeat the steps in Jeremy31's solution, and even then you may still end up receiving errors. I suggest you click on `show details` next time you receive an error and you open up another question here on askubuntu. It's a great chance to learn a lot.

Comment: By the way, I don't remove the line `managed=true` to false, and it works

Now, I'll reinstall ubuntu system, do the same way to create wireless connection and will write here, for describe what happened

It'll take about 30 min

Comment: Okay, good luck. Thanks for clarifying about `managed=true`.

Comment: Just now, I'm connected to wi-fi :)

I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04, did what said @jessenorton; and @Jeremy31; and it works :)

Thanks a lot!