# Installing "firmware-b43-installer" offline

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.10, broadcom

How can I install **firmware-b43-installer** driver if I can't connect to internet by wire?

Comment: If you think it is better that I ask this question inside the comments of question mentioned above, then let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: did you read my quesiton? I know it is a duplicate of that question but my problem is related to some special unknown case in that question.

Comment: Nothing is unknown. Did you see the table? It is `firmware-b43-installer`.

Comment: I am using 15.10 version. for that version it is unknown.

Comment: It does not matter. Just install it and report how it works.

Comment: I update the question with the result

Comment: Why did you install `bcmwl-kernel-source`, when it was recommended here and there to install `firmware-b43-installer`? Remove it.

Comment: Can you connect to internet by wire?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to install `firmware-b43-installer`.

If you do not have an alternative internet connection, do it this way.

If you installed `bcmwl-kernel-source`, then remove it.

```
    sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

1. Download these files

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_015-9_amd64.deb
http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2

2. Copy them to your Ubuntu Home folder.
3. Run in terminal

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_015-9_amd64.deb
   tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
   sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
   ```
4. Reboot or run:

   ```
   sudo modprobe b43
   ```

**Note:** For 32-bit systems download http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_019-2_i386.deb instead of `amd64` and update the file name in the `dpkg` command.

**For Ubuntu 16.04** http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb should be installed or the `i386` alternative.

If you are having trouble finding another computer, an Android phone can be used as a USB modem. You can connect the phone and choose "USB modem" in settings.

Comment: What is the difference between this solution and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline?rq=1) one? I am asking this question because I have a serious problem with my wireless connection as it goes off frequently so I was thinking maybe there are some differences between solutions that may help me find the problem.

Comment: These are different drivers. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers This is a solution to install the firmware without an internet connection.

Comment: This worked for me in the installed system but not in the installer (which would be good to fetch updates).

Comment: I'm trying to create portable Linux install that can work on almost any  hardware. My Macbook's wifi works with the bcmwl drivers. However, for maximal compatibility, I want to also have the b43 driver installed so it can be auto-loaded when necessary. Hence , removing bcmwl is not  an option at all. So, can i install b43 drivers side-by-side with bcwml and have it do its job if i use a system which needs bcmwl and not b43 ?

Comment: b43 is always installed. It is part of linux kernel. But it needs firmware.

Comment: The download links above do no work anymore. Can anyone give new links?

Comment: Package numbers changed, but you can find new ones at the same place.

Comment: Indeed @Pilot6 you are right. I found these links: 
https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_019-7build2_amd64.deb & 
http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-6.30.163.46.tar.bz2

Comment: @Pilot6 I have followed your steps (with the new files I found) and my Wifi still doesn't work. It has worked before, but after the automatic updates from earlier this week, it stopped working.

Comment: You can ask a question. This is a wrong place for it.