# How can I download firmware-b43-installer without internet access?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I just got ubuntu installed on my laptop but I can't access the internet on it. I have a flashdrive and another laptop that's running windows and does have internet access. I tried downloading firmware-b43-installer to the windows laptop and then moving it over to the flashdrive. But I couldn't figure out how to install it from the flashdrive back onto the ubuntu computer. How can I get it installed onto my ubuntu computer?

Chill's sudo commands all seemed to go through but the internet still didn't work. The dmesg command gave a ton of output:`[   11.974594] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4331 WLAN found (core revision 29)

```
[   11.974985] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 9, Type 7 (HT), Revision 1

[   11.974995] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2059, Revision 0, Version 1

[   11.974996] b43-phy0 warning: 5 GHz band is unsupported on this PHY

[   11.982127] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode29_mimo.fw failed with error -2

[   11.982138] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode29_mimo.fw failed with error -2

[   11.982149] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw failed with error -2

[   11.982155] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw failed with error -2

[   11.982157] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found

[   11.982158] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found

[   11.982159] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.

[   12.009721] Modules linked in: b43 mac80211 cfg80211 ssb drbg ansi_cprng joydev dm_crypt applesmc input_polldev intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp uvcvideo kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_cirrus videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_codec_generic videobuf2_memops irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul btusb btrtl crc32_pclmul btbcm videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core btintel snd_hda_intel v4l2_common input_leds snd_hda_codec videodev snd_hda_core aesni_intel bcm5974 aes_x86_64 media lrw snd_hwdep gf128mul snd_pcm glue_helper bluetooth ablk_helper snd_seq_midi cryptd snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer bcma snd thunderbolt mei_me lpc_ich mei shpchp soundcore apple_gmux sbs acpi_als sbshc kfifo_buf industrialio apple_bl mac_hid r8169 mii parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic
```

Comment: Is it a .deb file?

Comment: if it is a `.deb` file you can install it by running `sudo dpkg -i firmware-b43-installer_015-9_all.deb` or whatever the deb file is named.

Comment: also, do you have the ability to connect via Ethernet cable to your router?

Comment: @MichaelLindman good advice, but I just looked up that package and it looks like it depends on the `b43-fwcutter` package. And the `firmware-b43-installer` package requires internet access, since all it does is start a download of the firmare from a server and unpack them. @Zach O I think your best bet would be to find a place to plug in an Ethernet cable, if at all possible.

Comment: @NickWeinberg Interesting, I've unpacked the `.deb` file and found that it gets `http://mirror2.openwrt.org/sources/broadcom-wl-5.10.56.27.3_mipsel.tar.bz2` so it'll be possible to install it manually but chili555s answer is a much easier solution.

Comment: try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access

Comment: @Mohit_Rajan I'll be honest, as a noob I have serious trouble following and understanding those instructions all the way through.

Comment: @NickWeinberg I don't at this time. I'd rather not go out and buy a new adapter for 20 dollars but I will if I have to. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing "fimware-b43-installer" offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730799/installing-fimware-b43-installer-offline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the file `b43.zip` from this forum thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316899&highlight=b43.zip Transfer it to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer on your flash drive. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, from the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp ~/Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

If your wireless doesn't start immediately, reboot.

From your `dmesg`, it appears that your device also requires the "mimo" firmware files. Please remove the older, unneeded folder from your desktop:

```
cd ~/Desktop
rm -r b43
```

On my Dropbox account, I have the newer firmware files. Please download this to your desktop: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/b43_newest.zip Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.'

Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

If your wireless doesn't start immediately, reboot.

Comment: Still no internet. Is there something else I can try? I have a BCM4331 chip ID, 14e4:4331 PCIID, and the bcma-pci-bridge kernel driver, if that helps...

Comment: Are there any clues at the terminal? `dmesg | grep b43` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: The sudo commands all seemed to go through. The dmesg command gave a ton of output:

Comment: the rfkill command outputs:`0: hci0: Bluetooth \n Soft blocked: no \n Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour