# After regular update from Ubuntu 14.04 wireless network is not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, updates

Wireless network is not detected, says Disconnected - you are offline on start. This has started happening only after I updated Ubuntu 14.04 through Software Updater.

I did try with downgrading libnl those 3 files to 302.21-1 but no use. I tried with sudo services network-manager restart but no use.

Tried with uninstalling and reinstalling driver but no use.

I also tried with Advance recovery but no use.

Please help with this issue.

---

```
shaukat@shk-Inspiron-1545:~$ lspci -knn|grep Net -A2
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]

shaukat@shk-Inspiron-1545:~$ grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43legacy
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb.
shaukat@shk-Inspiron-1545:~$
```

Regards, SHK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: This is one command, not two.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Other one is not showing any result, i waited for at least 7-10 mins but there were no result. Please suggest if i try it again. Regards, Shk.

Comment: There are no 2 commands: one and the other. It was supposed to be run as one command.

Comment: Please also run `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: My apologies, i am sending is now.. please suggest                  shaukat@shk-Inspiron-1545:~$ lspci -knn|grep Net -A2
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]

shaukat@shk-Inspiron-1545:~$ grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43legacy
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb.
shaukat@shk-Inspiron-1545:~$

Comment: Please paste it to your question. It is unreadable here. But it is clear what happened.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrong driver is installed, it blacklisted the correct one.

If the firmware is installed, you can enable Wi-Fi by

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

You also need to remove the wrong driver by

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: It is still not showing network. Do I need to give some more  commands?

Comment: Install `firmware-b43-installer` then.

Comment: It says missing destination file operand after 'firmware-b43-installer'

Comment: What do you run? The command is `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`.

Comment: It says unable to fetch some archive then apt-get update is also showing unable to lock administration directory etc.

Comment: You need to close all other applications or reboot. And you need to be connected to internet.

Comment: My windows is fine with Internet so can I download some files and put them there in Ubuntu... Ubuntu is not having network..

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/730813/167850

Comment: All worked fine. Now i have wireless. Shall i upgrade to 15.10 as updater is asking for it? do i need to complete any prerequisites? -- SHK.