# How do I install wireless drivers on my Dell D630 laptop without a wired connection?

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

I have been trying different things to get my Broadcom wireless card working on my Dell Latitude D630 laptop. Everything I have tried runs me into a dead end. I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it with the Ubuntu 14.04 installation disc in the disc drive. I am at the point where I'd like to go step by step with help from the community to resolve this issue. Note: I do not have a wired internet connection available to me, all I can do is download files to my phone and transfer them to my laptop by USB. Please help!

Comment: If your phone is a somehow modern smartphone - it must be otherwise you wouldn't be downloading with it - surely it can do USB tethering. That's all you need.

Comment: I have a Windows phone and there is no option for USB tethering, also I don't have a data plan for my phone, I only use it's Wi-Fi.

Comment: On that post I jumped to "[How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline/626653#626653)". After copying the two files to my home directory I ran in terminal: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
The terminal displays a bunch of activity and then says:
`depmod....`
`DKMS: install completed.`

Then it hangs there and nothing happens. All I can do is close the terminal and then it says `Close this terminal? There is still a process running in this terminal. Closing the terminal will kill it`

Comment: did you manage to get a solution in newer versions yet?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, after many hours of dealing with this, I finally found an answer. First, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 14.04. Then I followed the steps on this page: [Installing "firmware-b43-installer" offline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730799/installing-fimware-b43-installer-offline/730813#730813)

So for some reason the newer version of Ubuntu was causing the problem.