# Unable to connect to Internet by Ethernet or Wireless - HP530 [Ubuntu 16.04.1]

Tags: wireless, internet, broadcom, hp, ethernet

Today I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my laptop (HP530),
Ethernet and Wireless are not recognized and set up.
I've followed many different guides but I can't fix my problem.

There are some Output of different codes:

**lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4**

```
10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev01)
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux MarcoPolo 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:06:14 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

**lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net**

```
02:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82562ET/EZ/GT/GZ - PRO/100 VE (LOM) Ethernet Controller Mobile [8086:1068] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82562ET/EZ/GT/GZ - PRO/100 VE (LOM) Ethernet Controller Mobile [103c:30d5]
    Kernel driver in use: e100
    Kernel modules: e100
10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [103c:1364]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**iwconfig**

```
enp2s8    no wireless extensions.
```

lo        no wireless extensions.

**rfkill list**

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-gps: GPS
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed a wrong driver for your wireless adapter. Remove it this way:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then you will need to install firmware for your adapter. Use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/730813/167850) as a guide.