# Connecting Dell XPS M1530 to Wifi

Tags: wireless

I am trying to connect my 9 years old Dell XPS M1530 to Wifi. In the  "Additional Drivers" tab, I got the following:
[image]

I select the first option under "Broadcom Corporartion" but when I hit "Apply Changes" it instantly goes back to "Do not use the device". This is also happened in "Try Ubuntu" when I tried to test the Wifi connection prior to installation from bootable USB installation drive.

I searched through web but majority of solution assume accessibility to Ethernet connection and I don't have one.

I need a method to solve this issue offline. I need to say I am newcomer to Ubuntu so I would appreciate an answer appropriate to my shallow knowledge. I need also to say I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 and there (in Windows) I don't have any problem whatsoever connecting to Wifi.

Edit

Running the following command:
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

I got the following output:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have included the output of the command you advised in the edited question.

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of the terminal. Rather copy and paste the text in your question and then format it as **code** by highlighting the text and clicking on the **{_}** icon above the editing box.

Comment: See this answer for the offline guide. https://askubuntu.com/questions/730799/installing-firmware-b43-installer-offline @HaiderAtrah