# Can't connect to internet on Kubuntu 14.04, BCM4311

Tags: drivers, wireless, dell, broadcom

When I hover over the check box for WiFi it says "Wireless disabled". I don't have access to any form of internet on the laptop. It is a Dell Inspiron E1505.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311   
  802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing "firmware-b43-installer" offline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730799/installing-firmware-b43-installer-offline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong driver installed.

Connect to the internet by wire and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: I've done it, do you want me to post the results?

Comment: If you were connected to the internet, your Wi-Fi should work.

Comment: It still isn't working but I plugged in an Ethernet cable, or is there something else that I need to to with Ethernet?

Comment: When you plugged the Ethernet cable, could you connect to the internet?

Comment: What does `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` show now?

Comment: After checking, no it could not connect to the internet.

Comment: So use the offline guide. I gave you a link under your question.

Comment: It outputs the exact same thing.

Comment: Still `Kernel driver in use: wl`?

Comment: It's fixed, thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!