# Broadcom 802.11n ubuntu 20.04. Cannot install drivers

Tags: wireless, broadcom, offline

Today i installed fresh ubuntu linux on my acer aspire v5 , very old laptop, dual boot with windows 8.1. Since i cannot connect to internet via wire, i had to download drivers from internet, and install them manualy. i downloaded b43-fwcutter amd64, and firmware b43 installer, both in .deb file and wanted to install via console first, sudo apt install b43-fwcutter_019-4amd64 with and without .deb on the end. ( sorry im linux noob atm ) but i got error that package is not found, same with firmaware-b43-installer.deb. when i tried simply click on the icon, and install it via software installer, installation stuck on "pending" and start working again. Any clue how to fix that ? i installed 64 bit system, from live pendrive.

EDIT:

```
QLinux:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [105b:e04b]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Can you temporarily connect to internet using your phone connected to USB? It will be much easier?

Comment: i'll try to connect via phone, and i guess use apt-get . ill read about it and come back here if i didnt make it .

Comment: You install pacakges from deb files by e.g. `sudo apt install ./filename.deb`. But you need to run it from a directory where it is located. But using your phone you can do it by `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`.

Comment: i did, i moved files from usb to downloads directory, went there by cd command and then i typed into terminal, sudo apt install frimware-b43-installer , but i read that i have to install fwcutter first and so did i . both times, i got no such package found message. :/ i did check if any letter wasnt missing in my command.

Comment: You missed `./`

Comment: ill try with ./ thank you very much :)

Comment: But I don't see `b43` in your output. Please also add output of `grep b43 | /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: sudo apt install ./firmware[...].deb didnt work offline.
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1), some error about connection with host, 1 sec i show you gep b43

Comment: You are running wrong commands. See https://askubuntu.com/a/730813/167850

Comment: when i did grep b43 | /etc/modprobe.d/* got msg : permision denied,
when sudo grep b43 | /etc/modprobe.d/* , action never ended, i could write what ever i want and nothing was happening.

Comment: i dont know what typo is yet. but i have to take care of something, ill be back later, and when i found out what typo is . But thank you for help.

Comment: You can't install `firmware-b43-installer` offline from deb. But you can using other ways. But better is to use your phone.

Comment: I made a typo. The correct command is `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: aaaa that you mean, i accualy could not because i copy pasted this command in to file on pendrive and copy pasted it in console on linux, i only made typo in comment. This command was approved by console, and then console froze unnaturaly. Like something was happening but didnt finish and i could type in stuff without having nick@ubuntu[somestuff] ~/ infront of it like usualy. i didnt recive any message after entering that message.

Comment: I gave you a wrong command, sry

Comment: okay thanks, ill try to establisch thetering via phone to linux, and do this command again soon. thanks :)